# Select Into Outfile incorrect syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to execute a simple `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` query in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. I don't understand why this is giving me this error.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\datadump\sqldbdump.txt"
FROM dbo.alarms_2_2014
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'C:\datadump\sqldbdump.txt'.

Comment: SQL Server / T-SQL doesn't have a `INTO OUTFILE ...` capability ... that's a MySQL feature

Comment: Well, there you go. Appreciate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "C:\datadump\sqldbdump.txt"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM dbo.alarms_2_2014;
```

try this one it should work perfectly.